# IE + overflow: прокрутка страницы

Tags: css3, internet-explorer, explorer

Интересный глюк происходит в IE (не знаю, как в ранних версиях, пытаюсь адоптировать всё под IE9-11). Причём в остальных браузерах всё работает нормально, а вот IE... Ведь бывает так, что `height` больше 100% и тогда требуется убрать полосы прокрутки, `overflow: hidden` в помощь. Однако, если выделить текст мышкой и попытатся протащить мышь вниз страницы, то страница прокручивается! Пробовал Chrome/Firefox/Opera, даже Safari 5 под Windows: не прокручивается, IE9-11 - прокручивается. Есть ли способы разрешить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Если кому-то интересно: Internet Explorer 10 (и выше) включает CSS-свойство `-ms-scroll-limit`, которое и отвечает за это. В итоге, достаточно добавить эти строки кода в проект и ничего прокручиватся не будет:

```
-ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0;
```

В случае с IE9 и более ранними версиями следует использовать JavaScript. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/GTZ8e/) с JavaScript и CSS3.